# Enable CORS in ASP .NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I use cors in my BaseApiController.

```
[EnableCors("http://localhost", "Content-Type", "GET, PUT, POST")]
    public abstract class BaseApiController: System.Web.Http.ApiController{
{
....
}
```

Is there any way to set only first parameter origin in file Web.config in the following section.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Instead put this parameter into EnableCors attribute?

Comment: An attribute expression has to be a constant AFAIK, unfortunately. Someone may know better than me but that's my understanding.

Comment: Do you want to enable CORS globally in your application?

Comment: @AbbasAmiri I have done it globally by configuration in file WebConfig in AppStart folder.